# Como fazer um comentário em HTML?

Tags: html, comentários

Queria saber como fazer um comentário no PyCharm com HTML. O comentário em Python é `#`, em C é `//` ou `/* */`, e em HTML?

Comment: Complementando: em **Python**, você pode comentar com várias linhas com o `'''`.

Comment: Eu havia editado a resposta errada, e agora acertei, só pra deixar claro da confusão que fiz, eu tinha colocado conteúdo que era pra minha resposta na do Guto Xavier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em html o comentário é:

```
<!-- comentário -->
```

`<!--` início do comentário

`-->`  fim do comentário

Comment: Me desculpe, eu fui editar a minha resposta e acabei editando a sua reverti agora.

Answer (score 8):

PyCharm nada tem a ver com isso, ele é apenas um IDE. Leia [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Cada linguagem tem sua sintaxe para comentários e outras coisas. Em HTML é o `<!--` para abrir e `-->` para fechar. Não tem uma forma de comentário *inline* como é possível nas linguagens citadas.

Então pode fazer algo assim:

```
<div id = "exemplo">
<!-- comente aqui o que quer -->
<p>abc</p>
```

Outros exemplos:

```
Tem um texto aqui <!-- the middle of --> com comentário no meio.

<!--
Pode ter
várias linhas de
comentário
-->

<div class="exemplo">
Pode ter uma construção normal e simular o *inline* desde que abra e feche.<br>
</div> <!-- /.exemplo -->
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Comment.html).