# Atribuir Valor a uma variavel que o usuário coloca C#

Tags: c#, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

Estou aprendendo C# (Ainda bem no inicio do aprendizado) e vi que qualquer coisa que o usuário insere pelo "Console.ReadLine();" é considerada como uma string automaticamente pelo Visual Studio, mas como faço para converter o valor para outro tipo de variável?
A parte do "Nome" funciona normalmente pois é uma variável do tipo "string", mas a parte da "Idade" eu não consigo fazer a atribuição dela pois ela é "int", o que eu teria que acrescentar ou mudar para funcionar? (não liguem para o último readline, ele é só para o programa não fechar automático)

```
        string nome;
        int idade;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Insira seu nome: ");
        nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("insira sua idade: ");
        idade = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("seu nome é:"+ nome);
        
        Console.WriteLine("sua idade é:"+ idade);
        
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `é considerada como uma string automaticamente pelo Visual Studio` não, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101. E a resposta dada só funciona em exercício se a pessoa digitar o valor certinho, dá erro em aplicação real. è bom o pessoal que vem ao SOpt ficar atento porque hoje boa parte das respostas dadas estão ensinando fazer errada, já foi o tempo que as respostas eram quase sempre boas.

Comment: @Maniero fique a vontade para postar a sua resposta.

Comment: Não precisa, isso já foi respondido uma quantidade enorme de vezes. Leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8573/101

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Você precisa converter o que é digitado para `int` primeiro, aqui eu usei a função `Convert.ToInt32()`

```
string nome;
int idade;
        
Console.WriteLine("Insira seu nome: ");
nome = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("insira sua idade: ");
idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
Console.WriteLine("seu nome é:"+ nome);
        
Console.WriteLine("sua idade é:"+ idade);
```

Fonte do [SO-Eng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input)

Comment: entendi o que vc fez, aproveitando, como faria para converter em outros tipo de string? tipo float, decimal, double, bool, string e char? eu não sei o motivo, mas eu nao consigo achar nada relacionado a isso

Comment: @BrenoLeonetti Você pode continuar usando o Convert, se tiver autocomplete na sua IDE, vai ver que ao dar o Convert. vai aparecer um leque de opções, pra float seria Convert.ToDouble(), também tem as opções relacionadas ao int.Parse() e para um double double.Parse()