# O que são os "Rich headers" presentes em executáveis compilados com Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .exe

Há algumas fontes na internet mencionando o "Rich Headers" que o Visual Studio embute em seus EXEs compilados. Algumas fontes dizem que esses artefatos incluem informações rastreáveis e que podem ajudar a determinar onde foi compilado e quem o compilou, mas não sei se é verdade.

Por ex, ao compilar um executável e linkar ele utilizando o Microsoft Linker, que é automático desde o Visual Studio 2013, estes cabeçalhos são encontrados no arquivo de saída:

```
00e1520d e1 21005 10 [C++] VS2013 build 21005
00df520d df 21005  1 [ASM] VS2013 build 21005
00de520d de 21005  1 [LNK] VS2013 build 21005
```

O que são estes cabeçalhos? O que representam, armazenam e para que servem? Eles também são inclusos em executáveis emitidos para .NET e Native AOT?

Comment: Não parece ter nada demais, pelo demonstrado, não sei se tem algo mais. Tenho quase certeza que se inclui algo mais (que te identifique) é porque você mandou incluir. Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101. Não parece ter nada de excepcional nisso.